# How to securely manage certificates with desktop installations

Tags: security, .net-core, electron, client-certificates

I have an application that was built using Electron, Angular 8, dotnet core 3.1, that is used to monitor some hardware over CAN. It logs data and should sent this data to IoT Core on AWS.

To do that AWS gives you several certificate files.

Since the application is installed on the desktop I was wondering where I should keep the certificate files. What is the safest way so that nosy people inspecting the folder structure or decompiling the code don't see them or at least can't decrypt them?

Comment: Would the person voting to close this question tell me why?